# Timeouts calling SQL from C#: TransactionScope appears to override DbCommand CommandTimeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout, transactionscope

My understanding of these timeouts is as follows:

- `DbCommand.CommandTimeout` controls how long a Sql command will run for, before spontaneously ceasing and returning control to the C# calling code (in the form of a thrown timeout `SqlException`.)

  - i.e. if your query is `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' And you set your` DbCommand.CommandTimeout`to`00:00:01`, then your C# will throw an Exception after 1 second, not 5 seconds.
- The `scopeTimeout` ctor parameter on `TransactionScope` controls whether or not the scope rolls-back when it is disposed. It cannot interrupt a SQL execution - it will only trigger an Exception when the `scope.Dispose()` method is called.

  - i.e. if your query is `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'`
    And you set your `scopeTimeout` to `00:00:01`, then your C# will throw an Exception after **5** seconds, not be interrupted before then.

I written tests to verify both of these behaviours in my codebase, on the assumption that only one of the 2 kinds of timeout is present, and they work fine.

If I create the test for "scopeTimeout = 3s; CommandTimeout = 1s; SQL WAITFOR = 5s", then I expect that the CommandTimeout will take precedence and it'll throw a SQL Exception after 1 second. A Test confirms that to be true too.

And finally if I create the test for "scopeTimeout = 1s; CommandTimeout = 3s; SQL WAITFOR = 5s", then I would have expected that the command will still run for 3s before throwing, and then the scope will do [something, TBC] when it Disposes.

But what I actually see is that the SQL runs for the full 5 seconds! i.e. ...

**Setting a short scopeTimeout appears to disable the CommandTimeout entirely!!**

**Why does this happened, and is there a way to prevent it?**

Comment: I'm definitely tempted to "solve" my problem by saying "sod it ... all server side transactionScopes have Infinite timeouts" ... but I was hoping to fully grok what was going on before I did so 

Comment: Further testing has confirmed that: A) This is definitely true of raw `TransactionScope`s and `System.Data.SqlClient` sql objects (it wasn't anything to do with a library). B) The point at which the TransactionScope affects the SqlTimeout is the point at which the `SqlConnection` is `.Open()`ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"all server side transactionScopes have Infinite timeouts"  is a good approach for SQL Server.

And the point in your code where you create the TransactionScope you don't really know whether any operations inside the transaction might be long-running.